# Why is this initialization of final fields wrong in Dart?

Tags: constructor, dart, final

I have a simple class with two final fields, one of them is a map to store the data and another is a step function that updates the data when called:

```dart
class Data
{

  //for each name a list of observations
  final Map<String,List<double>> _dataMap;

  /**
   * the update step
   */
  final Step _updateStep;
```

`Step` is just a `typedef`.

Now, I want a constructor which has one parameter: a function that takes a reference `Map<...>` and returns a new `Step`. This seems logical to me, the updater needs a reference to the map to update it.

Why then this constructor fails?

```dart
  Data(Step initializer(Map<String,List<double>> dataReferences))
  : _dataMap = new Map(),
  _updateStep = initializer(_dataMap);
```

The error is in the second step

> illegal implicit access to receiver 'this';

What? How does that leak this? How to fix it?

Comment: I get `Only static members can be accessed in initializers.` Can you please check the code you posted. The constructor is named `AgentData` the class is named `Data` something seems to be wrong/incomplete.

Comment: sorry AgentData is a typo due to simplifying this exampe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Günter Zöchbauer already explained the reason for your error.

Here is a workaround:

```dart
Data(Step initializer(Map<String,List<double>> dataReferences))
  : this._internal(initializer, new Map());

Data._internal(initializer, map)
  : _dataMap = map,
    _updateStep = initializer(map);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are reading from `_dataMap` (`initializer(_dataMap)`). `_datamap` is a field of `this` it is not an argument. You can't read fields from 'this' in constructor initializers as the error message says.

Comment: So how would I go on using my fields in the constructor then?

Comment: You can assign to it and in the constructor body you can read from them but that is to late for initializing final fields. I think you can't initialize two final fields with mutual dependency. You need to 'calculate' the values before you pass them to the constructor and just assign the result using `(this.dataMap, this._updateStep) or using the initializer list.

Comment: Thanks, you are right but it just seems like a pointless dance for what would be very straightforward in Java.

Comment: Dart is young and the designers didn't want to unleash all possible features at once because it complicates the language. It seams they want the language to stabilize and learn in detail what problems arise with the current design before improving and refining the rules and add new features (see also mixin for example where they clearly communicate that the restrictions should be lifted at some point)
Dart has many new concepts and all features need to transpile to JavaScript too. No one can do this all in one big release. Java needed 20 years to become what it is now.

Comment: If you think Dart should support this create a feature request at http://dartbug.com.

Comment: Sure, don't misunderstand me. I understand dart's design philosophy and I appreciate.

Comment: No prob, I don't know where people come from and what their expectations are. The Dart team is always curious what problems people run into therefore I think a feature request would be great.